# _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRPhoneAuthProvider", referenced from: objc-class-ref in LoginVC.o Getting this error

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

Showing All Messages

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRPhoneAuthProvider", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref in LoginVC.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
>   x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests that the compiler could not able to find the **FIRPhoneAuthProvider** class while building the **LoginVC for X86_64 ** architecture. It might because of Architecture settings.

Check the **Build Active Architectures Only** setting from the Build Settings. Make sure that this should be same for your **application target** and for **cocoapods** target.

If you still face the issue, post the screenshot of your Xcode with build setting.