# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Twitter",

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Twitter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseTwitterAuthUI(FUITwitterAuth.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am having that error when I want to build the project.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem in a new project - added `FirebaseUI` to the pod file now fails to link with the above error. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @AshleyMills yeap. check here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/378

Comment: Brilliant, that solved it - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Error Explanation :**
The error suggests that the compiler could not able to find the **Twitter** class while building the  **FirebaseTwitterAuthUI** for **arm64**  architecture. It is because of Architecture settings.

Check the **Build Active Architectures Only** setting from the Build Settings. Make sure that **this should be same** for your **application target** and for the **cocoapods target**.

If you still face the issue, post the screenshot of your Xcode with build setting.

**Target -> Build Settngs -> Build Active Architecture Only.**

Build Active Architecture flag **=> Yes** indicates that build the current app only for the selected simulator architecture. It will make build faster.

Build Active Architecture flag **=> No** indicates that build the current app for all the architectures.

So if you have multiple targets with different options, you will be able to get this kind of error.

**Build Active Architecture flag => Yes for Debug and => No for Release mode.**

[image]

check this :[_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRPhoneAuthProvider", referenced from: objc-class-ref in LoginVC.o Getting this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47864085/objc-class-firphoneauthprovider-referenced-from-objc-class-ref-in-loginvc/47865793#47865793)

Comment: Where is Build Active Architectures Only setting?

Comment: I checked and all settings are same for the application target and cocoapods target. Yes for debug and No for release

Comment: upload the screenshot of Firbase and Twitter project settings.

Comment: it seems to be a bundle target. show me all the cocoapods targets ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161560/discussion-between-kumar-reddy-and-utku-dalmaz).

Answer (score 0):

Check that the framework you are importing has that architecture defined:

In terminal run:

lipo -info

The output should be something like:arm64 armv7 armv7s

If not, 
1. your library is wrong and is missing that architecture
2. Your build settings doesn’t include that architecture 
3. You are not linking the library correctly