# xcode9 build faild : "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64"

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

```
<code>
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_ConectorIOSCopy", referenced from:
      _SDKConectorIOS_ConectorIOSCopy_m3674919636 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o
      _SDKConectorIOS_copyTextToClipboard_m3727867548 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o
     (maybe you meant: _SDKConectorIOS_ConectorIOSCopy_m3674919636)
  "_ConectorIOSGetRoomId", referenced from:
      _SDKConectorIOS_ConectorIOSGetRoomId_m801503328 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o
      _SDKConectorIOS_GetRoomId_m1961511992 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o
      _SDKManager_GetRoomId_m3742749013 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o
     (maybe you meant: _SDKConectorIOS_ConectorIOSGetRoomId_m801503328)
  "_ConectorIOSShare", referenced from:
      _SDKConectorIOS_ConectorIOSShare_m3217100158 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o
      _SDKConectorIOS_ShareForIOS_m3159116608 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o
     (maybe you meant: _SDKConectorIOS_ConectorIOSShare_m3217100158)
  "_ConectorIOSPayAction", referenced from:
      _SDKConectorIOS_ConectorIOSPayAction_m345257034 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o
      _SDKConectorIOS_BuyRuquestForIOS_m1026682359 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o
     (maybe you meant: _SDKConectorIOS_ConectorIOSPayAction_m345257034)
  "_getIPv6", referenced from:
      _IOSIPv6_getIPv6_m4159137885 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _IOSIPv6_getIPv6_m4159137885)
  "_GetVersion", referenced from:
      _IOSGameStart_GetVersion_m700337066 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
      _IOSGameStart_GetGameVersion_m710226816 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
     (maybe you meant: _Ivw_GetVersion, 

_GameLink_GetVersion_m2049850782_MetadataUsageId , _GameLinkImpl_GetVersion_m1271703472_MetadataUsageId , _SDKManager_GetVersion_m2568922873 , _IOSGameStart_GetVersion_m700337066 , _GameLink_GetVersion_m2049850782 , _SDKConectorIOS_GetVersion_m545450128 ,
_GameLinkImpl_GetVersion_m1271703472 )
      "_GetLoginParaFromXcode", referenced from:
          _IOSGameStart_GetLoginParaFromXcode_m412360857 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
         (maybe you meant: _IOSGameStart_GetLoginParaFromXcode_m412360857)
      "_ConectorIOSGetVersion", referenced from:
          _SDKConectorIOS_ConectorIOSGetVersion_m1370711288 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o
          _SDKConectorIOS_GetVersion_m545450128 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o
          _SDKManager_GetVersion_m2568922873 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o
         (maybe you meant: _SDKConectorIOS_ConectorIOSGetVersion_m1370711288)
      "_InvokeGame", referenced from:
          _IOSGameStart_InvokeGame_m3031031562 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_2.o
         (maybe you meant: _IOSGameStart_InvokeGame_m3031031562)
      "__BuglySetTag", referenced from:
          _BuglyAgent_SetCurrentScene_m1966723701 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
          _BuglyAgent__BuglySetTag_m2083808208 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
         (maybe you meant: _BuglyAgent__BuglySetTag_m2083808208)
    </code>
```

unity version : 5.6.3f

xcode : 9.2

target sdk : 8.0

And other. Tell me how you can solve this problem. I did not find the right solution, although I struggle with this not for the first day.

Comment: check my previous answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891146/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-objc-class-twitter/47891686#47891686. Let me know if this does help.